# Why does the translator use "arcilla" in one instance and "barro" in another for "clay"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

In "Tom Sawyer" there's a case where "clay" is first translated as "arcilla"

**English**:

*The boys began to quiet down to whispers, now, for the stillness and gloom of the place oppressed their spirits. They went on, and presently entered and followed Tom's other corridor until they reached the "jumping-off place." The candles revealed the fact that it was not really a precipice, but only a steep **clay** hill twenty or thirty feet high. Tom whispered:*

**Spanish**:

Siguieron hablando en voz muy baja, porque el silencio y la lobreguez de aquel lugar sobrecogía sus espíritus. Marcharon adelante y entraron después por la otra galería, explorada por Tom, hasta que llegaron al borde cortado a pico. Con las velas pudieron ver que no era realmente un despeñadero, sino un declive de **arcilla** de siete o diez metros de altura. Tom mur-muró:

...and then as "barro":

**English**:

"Tom," said he, "auntie has been waiting for you all the afternoon. Mary got your Sunday clothes ready, and everybody's been fretting about you. Say -- ain't this grease and **clay**, on your clothes?"

**Spanish**:

— Tom —dijo—, la tía te ha estado aguardando toda la tarde. Mary te había ya sacado el traje de los domingos, y todo el mundo estaba rabiando contra ti. Dime, ¿no es sebo y **barro** es-to que tienes en la ropa?

Why the inconsistency?

Comment: *clay* as arcilla means that it was made for pottery; as *barro* means that it comes from earth.

Comment: So it should be "barro" in both cases, right?

Comment: Clay is 'arcilla' and 'Barro' is mud. They are almost the same thing but you usually use mud (barro) when referring to dirty cloths or pottery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **clay** /kleɪ/ n
>
> 1. a very fine-grained material that consists of hydrated aluminium silicate, quartz, and organic fragments and occurs as sedimentary rocks, soils, and other deposits. It becomes plastic when moist but hardens on heating and is used in the manufacture of bricks, cement, ceramics, etc
> 2. earth or mud in general

<sup>Collins Concise English Dictionary</sup>

In the first case, it's a technical description of the material. `Arcilla`, a word not common except when talking about pottery, rivers and clay hills, is adequate.

In the second case, the translator had to decide: Is Aunt Polly referring specifically to the material used in pottery, or is she using the word `clay` to refer to mud or earth in general? I think, and I think the translator also thought, that the latter is more likely (why would Aunt Polly be so specific?) and chose to translate it as `barro`.

Comment: I agree, it is said "tengo barro en los zapatos" (no one cares about the chemical composition nor the size of the particles), for example. Pero "montaña de tierra" me suena mucho más natural (aunque sea menos correcto)

Comment: The thing is, _barro_ can mean both _mud_ or _clay_ (as used in pottery), but _arcilla_ just has the "technical" meaning. For example, you can cook in a _cazuela de barro_.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the words "barro" and "arcilla" do not mean the same on their most strict way, they both can be used in an informal way of speaking to mean a kind of wet dirt.

I assume the translator didn't pay much attention to those little details. However, the message is still transmitted.